# If $F$ is a set of functions prove that for every set $A$ there exists a $B$ so that $A\subseteq B$, $B$ is closed for $F$ and $B$ is minimal;

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It's easy to prove this result with just one function, so it will also apply for a union of functions but I have no idea what to do with composition.

Edit:I think i have an solution let $H0$=$A$ ;$H(n+1)$=∪{f(x);x∈$Hn$,f∈$F$}
if B=∪{$Hn$} it posses the required criteria

Comment: Why is this different when F is larger?

Comment: It isn't different I just had to think a little more.The fact that all these function will have the same domain (as Robert pointed out, thank you) escaped ma head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably all these functions have the same domain and codomain $X$, and you're talking about sets $A \subseteq X$.  Let $B$ be the intersection of all sets $S$ such that $A \subseteq S$ and $S$ is closed under $F$.